# Angular - Load another lazily loaded module with a lazily loaded module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I'm looking for a way to load another lazily loaded module aside a lazily loaded module, because one module need the lazily loaded store of the other...

Should I rethink my architecture or there is a way to do this in Angular?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. You lazily load a module the exact same way from the bootstrap module and from another one. Which issues exactly are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

You can import and export the one lazy loaded module to the other. 
This will lead to declaring multiple times any routes that exist for the second one.
In this case just split the shared code to a third module that will be imported to both lazy loaded modules.

Answer (score 0):

I ended with this working solution : because my needs was to access the ngrx store lazyloaded by the other module, i just imported the reducer needed in the main app Root store directly, i also imported effects needed in the root module app

*edit : there is a smart way with using guards for checking the presence of the state, if not , the guard launch a store action who load the things*

example :

```
checkStore(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(myselector).pipe(
        tap(loaded => {
            if (!loaded) {
                this.store.dispatch(new store.loadThings());
            }
        }),
        filter(loaded => loaded),
        take(1)
    );
 }
```

*thanks to Todd Motto for the tips*